# How can I run four bots on the AI Challenge Planet Wars?

Tags: c++

I'm running a contest with my friends, and we're using c++.  How can I run the game with four bots instead of two?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to set up a tournament. You can organize it as a two round (semifinals+finals) or 3 rounds (full competition).

Comment: What I want to do is run more than two bots on one map. Can I do that? I see the colors for multiple players at the top, so I am lead to believe that there is a way.